# Add weeks in decimal value in php

Tags: php, date, strtotime

I am trying to add weeks in decimal values like 1.5, 2.5 to date through strtotime() function. But its not giving correct result. I am using it like:

```
$start_date = "2015-01-01";

$date = strtotime(date("Y-m-d", strtotime($start_date)) . " +3.5 weeks");

$date = date("Y-m-d",$date);

echo $date;
```

And its giving 2015-02-04 as output. When added non decimal values like:

```
$date = strtotime(date("Y-m-d", strtotime($start_date)) . " +3 weeks");
```

It gives perfect results.

Any thought on it?

Comment: `strtotime('+3 weeks', $start_date)` would save some typing :)

Comment: What's half a week anyway? A week has seven days, so it's either 3 or 4 days.

Comment: Thanks so much @Ja͢ck ... I'll surely do that :)

Comment: try `$date = strtotime($start_date  . " +3.5 weeks");`

Comment: @Eugen, its same as of what I am  already doing, same result.

Comment: @Ja͢ck - [how many days are in a week?](http://forum.bodybuilding.com/showthread.php?t=107926751)

Comment: @Ja͢ck, I am fine with 3 days, even if script does it to 4. Its fine too. I just want to make it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$date = '2015-01-01';

$weeks = "2,3,4,4.5";

foreach(explode(",", $weeks) as $week) {
 print $week."\n";
 $hours = $week * 24 * 7;
 print $hours."\n";
 print date("Y-m-d", strtotime("{$date} +{$hours} hours"))."\n";
}
```

Comment: You can remove the + before days and hours : strtotime("+3 weeks 3 days 12 hours",$start_date);

Comment: Thank Eugen, actually I already know this. My problem is that $start_date will be a dynamic value and also the adding period e.g days, weeks, months. And even if input is a week, there will be values like 2,3,4,4.5 etc. So, I am trying to find an automated way to deal with all of the week values in one query.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this logic, multiply your week decimal or not like 1,2,2.5,3,3.5 and multiply it by the amount of hours in a week :

```
$week = 2.5;
$desired = '+ '.$week*168.' hours';
$date = strtotime($desired, $start_date);
```

However, why playing with strings when you can just play with hours or seconds integers and doing a simple addition ?

Comment: Yes, but thanks to you too :) @Christophe Willemsen, +1 for you too mate